# How to share a folder between two users on the same linux laptop

Tags: linux, filesystems, shared-folders, shared-file

1. Ubuntu 20.4 installed with user Marco
2. created other user Polo by going to |settings > Users > Add User|
3. created "commonDir" folder in Marco's home directory. |right click > new folder|
4. logged out from Marco. |click top right corner > power Off/Log Out > Log Out|
5. logged into Polo
6. navigated to Polo's home directory but "commonDir" folder was not visible.

What should I do in order to make it accessible by both the users.?

(Still working my way through linux commands. That's why I'm using UI to do all the things)

Comment: So you created CommonDir in Marco's $HOME, lets say /home/Marco, and created Polo's user (with his own $HOME != Marco's $HOME let's say /home/Polo). If so, why would you expect Commondir (/home/Marco/Commondir) to automagically appear when listing /home/Polo ?

Comment: I don't know how to set attributes for that folder so that it'll become visible to other user accounts. Maybe I'm doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should the commonDir folder be readable by both or writable by both?

If you want it to be *readable* by the other user:
Try `$ cd ../Marco/commonDir` from Polo's home directory.
With the GUI:
Go to Files, and click Other Locations. Click on *home*, then *Polo*, then *commonDir*.

If you want commonDir to be writeable, try as Marco:

```
$ sudo groupadd commonDir
$ sudo chgrp commonDir ~marco/commonDir 
$ sudo usermod -a -G commonDir Polo 
$ sudo chmod 775 ~marco/commonDir
```

Then as Polo:

```
$ newgrp commonDir
$ cd ~marco/commonDir
$ gnome-text-editor whatever_is_in_the_folder
```

Note: You have to do the above every time you want to write to things in the commonDir directory.

Comment: Maybe symlinking could make accesses easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot @lovecodeabc Very precise and least complex solution.